# Updating multiple span text from respective value with jQuery each

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a bunch of timestamps in my page that I want Javascript to convert to the user's local timezone. In my template, I drop the timestamps in ISO format into a special span class, and want to iterate over each span to do the conversion. Here's my code:

```
$('.tzdate').each( function(){
    $(this).text( Date( $(this).val() ) );
  });
```

The conversion works perfectly. The only problem is that every single span is updated to the same value. I thought using $(this) inside of an $.each() would work but it doesn't seem to in either Chrome or Firefox.

Any suggestions?

[edit]
VisioN's answer got me started, because it is now actually doing the date conversion and not just using the timestamp at the time the script was run. Now the problem is setting the text to the Date doesn't seem to be working. Some updated code:

```
$( ".tzdate" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $(this).text() );
  console.log( index + ": " + new Date( $(this).text() ) );
  var a = new Date( $(this).text() )
  $(this).text ( a ) 
});
```

Output:

```
0: 2013-01-24T18:42:21
0: Thu Jan 24 2013 13:42:21 GMT-0500 (EST)
1: 2013-01-24T18:35:08
1: Thu Jan 24 2013 13:35:08 GMT-0500 (EST)
2: 2013-01-24T18:42:21
2: Thu Jan 24 2013 13:42:21 GMT-0500 (EST)
3: 2013-01-24T18:40:27
3: Thu Jan 24 2013 13:40:27 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

But the span's text doesn't actually update. Thoughts? Thanks!

[Final edit]
Need a .toString() after the Date object when setting the span's text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) keyword.

It will create a new `Date` object out of ISO date string, and will fix the problem:

```
$(this).text( new Date( this.value ).toString() );
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out right after you posted your answer, but I'm still having some trouble. Could you check out my edit?

Comment: Looks like I just need a .toString() on there. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Joseph Yes, it is true: `.toString()` returns the string value of the object to the element contents.